# Automatically split an expression and use TrigFactor to solve the parts

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I want to simplify the following expression:

```
1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la - lb + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x+y]*lf - Sin[x+y]*lf)
```

I used `TrigFactor` and it didn't work, the expression didn't even change.

The solution was to split the expression into parts and use `TrigFactor`. So I did this:

```
TrigFactor[1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la)] + TrigFactor[1/2*-lb] +
     TrigFactor[1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x+y]*lf - Sin[x+y]*lf)]
```

And I got the result that I wanted:

> ```
> Cos[pi/6 + x]*la - lb/2 + Cos[pi/6+x+y]*lf
> ```

The only problem is that I'll receive my expressions from matrices multiplications and they'll get even more complicated.

So, I want to know if there's a way to split my expressions and use `TrigFactor` automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to collect scaling factors

`ce = Collect[
  1/2 (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] la - Sin[x] la - lb + Sqrt[3] Cos[x + y] lc - 
     Sin[x + y] lc), {la, lb, lc}]`

`-(lb/2) + 1/2 la (Sqrt[3] Cos[x] - Sin[x]) + 
 1/2 lc (Sqrt[3] Cos[x + y] - Sin[x + y])`

which allows one to use

`TrigFactor /@ ce`

`-(lb/2) + la Cos[\[Pi]/6 + x] + lc Cos[\[Pi]/6 + x + y]`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be

```
Total@TrigFactor@
Level[HornerForm[
1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la - lb + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x + y]*lf - 
   Sin[x + y]*lf)], 1]
```

I just put it in Horner Form, Broke the sum terms into a list(`Level["expression", 1]`), factored each list element, then added them all together.

The output in this case being what you desired,

```
-(lb/2) + la Cos[Pi/6 + x] + lf Cos[Pi/6 + x + y]
```

I'm not sure how far this generalizes, but it works here.

*Addendum from comment suggestion:*

Mr. Wizard brings up a more efficient idea, I think what he's saying should look like:

```
Map[TrigFactor, 
HornerForm[
1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la - lb + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x + y]*lf - 
 Sin[x + y]*lf)]]
```

It produces the same result, fewer functions. I am sure we could make it even shorter, but that's the idea.

Addendum 2: Finally, just for one liner fun, I can't make it any shorter than

```
TrigFactor /@ HornerForm@
(1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la - lb + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x + y]*lf - Sin[x + y]*lf))
```

Comment: I do not believe you need `Level` and `Total`; you can `Map` across a `Plus` expression.  `TrigFactor /@ HornerForm[expr]`

Comment: I see it. That work's well. I think I'll add that to my post if you do not mind.

Comment: I do not mind; I commented so that you might do so. :-)

Comment: Thank's Mr. Wizard. :))

Answer (score 1):

```
expr = 1/2*(Sqrt[3]*Cos[x]*la - Sin[x]*la - lb + Sqrt[3]*Cos[x + y]*lf - Sin[x + y]*lf)

FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, TrigFactor}]
```

> -(lb/2) + la Cos[π/6 + x] + lf Cos[π/6 + x + y]